# How to set up karma with Jenkins CI server on windows 7 enterprise?

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, karma-runner

I have already Jenkins CI server set up and installed Node.js and karma .But I dont know the parametrs for the jenkin's job.Please let me know if any tutorial or example available.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just run karma as a windows batch job. Therefore you have to check that karma is on the global PATH variable of the system. 
Another thing is to ensure that 'singleRun: true,' is set in your karma config.
And don´t forget to set 'CHROME_BIN' to the chrome executable respectively 'FIREFOX_BIN' if using FireFox.

What I have not solved yet is that Chrome does not exit after executing the tests :(